# Gathering wealth and not spending - Islam view

Tags: money

What is Islam's perspective on gathering too much money and not investing and letting them flow?

For example, one desires to save too much money, without utilizing that money anywhere.

Is there anything from Qur'an and prophetic hadith related to this topic?

Comment: You are required to pay Zakat on wealth at a rate of 2.5% per annum.

Answer (score 1):

It is not forbidden to collect riches as long as the duties (zakat, payment of debt) are fulfilled but it is not the path of a true believer:

> Abu Huraira reported that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) had said:
> Richness does not lie in the abundance of (worldly) goods but richness is the richness of the soul (heart, self).

[Muslim 1051](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1051)

> Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
> "Richness is not having many possessions, but richness is being content with oneself."

[Tirmidi 2373](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2373)

Abu Sa'eed narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
"The poor Muhajirin will enter Paradise before the rich among them by five hundred years."

[Tirmidi 2351](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2351)

A certain punishment is related in this hadith

> Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (s.a.w) said:
> "The poor Muslims are admitted into Paradise before their rich by half a day. And that is five hundred years."

[Tirmidi 2354](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2354)

And a hadith of Jesus says

> Jesus said again, “Dear children, it is very hardf to enter the Kingdom of God. In fact, it is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle than for a rich person to enter the Kingdom of God!”
> The disciples were astounded. “Then who in the world can be saved?” they asked.
> Jesus looked at them intently and said, “Humanly speaking, it is impossible. But not with God. Everything is possible with God.”

[Mark 10:24-27](https://biblehub.com/mark/10-25.htm)

And in the Quran

> As for man, whenever his Lord tests him, and grants him honour, and blesses him, he says, ‘My Lord has honoured me.’ (15) But when He tests him and tightens for him his provision, he says, ‘My Lord has humiliated me.’ (16) No indeed! No, you do not honour the orphan, (17) and do not urge the feeding of the needy. (18) You eat the inheritance rapaciously, (19) and love wealth with much fondness. (20) No indeed! When the earth is levelled to a plain, (21) and your Lord [’s edict] arrives with the angels in ranks, (22) the day when hell is brought [near], man will take admonition on that day, but what will that admonition avail him? (23)

[Al-Fajr 89:14-22](https://tanzil.net/#trans/en.itani/89:14)